# using PayWithAmazon with symfony 2 - installed with Composer

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, payment, amazon-pay

I installed this package via composer:

```
composer require amzn/login-and-pay-with-amazon-sdk-php
composer update
```

I added this to my Controller file:
use PayWithAmazon\Client;

... and would like to use the Client class, provided with this package.

`$amazonClient = new PayWithAmazon\Client($this->amazonCredentials);`

The error message of the framework:

```
ClassNotFoundException in CartController.php line 185: Attempted to load 
    class "Client" from namespace "**Microsite\FrontBundle\Controller\PayWithAmazon**".
Did you forget a "use" statement for e.g.
    "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Client",
    "Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Client",
    "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Client",
    "Guzzle\Service\Client" or "Guzzle\Http\Client"?
```

`

Can anyone tells me what i do wrong?
How do I change the namespace for "Client" class from `Microsite\FrontBundle\Controller\PayWithAmazon` to the right one?

(I did not have problems with other packages...)

Cheers
Greg

Comment: The right instiate:
$amazonClient = new \PayWithAmazon\Client($this->amazonCredentials);

Comment: `new PayWithAmazon\Client`  - why did you add the namespace before the class name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest you do follow

```
use PayWithAmazon\Client as AmazonClient;
...
$amazonClient = new AmazonClient($this->amazonCredentials);
```